# How to get not hardcode project path in Jenkins and mention the path in the Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: c#, jenkins, pipeline

Currently in my pipeline script I have 4 dlls that I am executing in Jenkins. 3 of the dll starts with the word Service and one of them starts with the word unit
Can I use wildcard here to pick out the once that starts with Search like Search% or $Search and then add a finally statement to execute the one that starts wit h unit..

I keep getting error when I use % or $ to mention the project file it gives me and error
"Project file does not exist"

```
 stage('Tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                def tests = ['dotnet test %WORKSPACE%/ServiceT1.dll',
                'dotnet test %WORKSPACE%/Service-JV.dll', 'dotnet test %WORKSPACE%/Service-or.dll',
                  'dotnet test %WORKSPACE%/unit-pr.dll']
                tests.each{test -> try{
                    bat 'dotnet test %WORKSPACE%/$Service'
                }catch(e){
                    echo e.toString()
                }
               
              }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find files](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) for that.

```
def tests = findFiles glob: "*.dll", excludes: <whatever you dont want>
```

Comment: thanks can you show me how can include this in the script please

Comment: you replace the `def tests = [ ... ] with it. If you want all dlls in the list you can omit the excludes part, otherwise put a pattern you want to exclude there.
You have to install the pipeline utility plugin, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: If your dlls are in subfolders you can use  glob: "**/*.dll" instead